# How to group this sql query according to time intervals?

Tags: sql, db2

I have data like these:

| Kod | HareketTarihi | HareketZamani | Miktar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 202001322-2 | 26.1.2021 | 15:47 | 26.10 |
| 202001322-2 | 27.1.2021 | 07:46:52 | 0.00 |
| 202001322-2 | 27.1.2021 | 09:48 | 102.00 |
| 202001322-2 | 27.1.2021 | 10:51 | 335.25 |

I would like to group like this:

| Kod | HareketTarih-Zamani | Miktar |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 202001322-2 | 26.01.2021 08:00 - 27.01.2021 08:00 | 26.10 |
| 202001322-2 | 27.01.2021 08:00 - 28.01.2021 08:00 | 437.25 |

How can i do that?

Comment: I am guessing that you could provide a simpler query to answer the question that you want answered.  Most of the stuff in your query is totally unrelated to your question.

Comment: You can be right. Below two tables show what i wanted. Forget to make SQL statement. I don't want you to write SQL Statement. I just want to know how to make it

Comment: Provide a simple SQL query that shows something you have in terms of grouping, then the desired output. Again, most of the stuff above in your question is unrelated and is just confusing or unnecessary reading

Comment: What would be the result value of `TRANSACTIONDATE` for source `TRANSACTIONDATE = '2021-01-01' AND TRANSACTIONTIME = '07:00'`? The same question is for `TRANSACTIONDATE = '2021-01-31' AND TRANSACTIONTIME = '09:00'`.

Comment: OK. I'll make it simplier

Comment: You should `GROUP BY Kod, CASE 
    WHEN HOUR(HareketZamani) < 8 
    THEN expr1(HareketTarihi)
    ELSE expr2(HareketTarihi)
  END`. Try to construct these 2 expressions depending on `HareketTarihi` on your own and update your question with such an attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Untested as I don't have your tables, but perhaps:

```
WITH (
select 
  Kod, 
  DATE((timestamp_format(HareketTarihi || ' ' || HareketZamani) - 8 hours)) as HareketTarihi,
  Miktar
from Table1 
) AS CTE1,
(select 
  Kod, 
  HareketTarihi as HareketTarihi,
  sum(Miktar) as Miktar
from CTE1
group by Kod, HareketTarihi
) AS CTE2,
Select 
  Kod,
  HareketTarihi || ' 08:00 - ' || (HareketTarihi + 1 day) || ' 07:59' as HareketTarih-Zamani,
  Miktar
from CTE2
```